# Convert a Pandas DataFrame to bin frequencies

Tags: python, pandas

using pandas, i know how to bin a single column but i'm struggling to figure how to do multiple columns  and then find a count (frequency) of the bins, as my dataframe has 20 columns. I know I could do the method I use for a single column 20 times, but I'm interested in learning a new better method.  here is head of the dataframe with 4 columns showing:

```
      Percentile1 Percentile2 Percentile3   Percentile4
395     0.166667    0.266667    0.266667    0.133333
424     0.266667    0.266667    0.133333    0.032258
511     0.032258    0.129032    0.129032    0.387097
540     0.129032    0.129032    0.387097    0.612903
570     0.129032    0.387097    0.612903    0.741935
```

i created the following bin array

```
output = ['0-10','10-20','20-30','30-40','40-50','50-60','60-70','70-80','80-90','90-100']
```

here is my desired output:

```
      Percentile1 Percentile2 Percentile3   Percentile4
395     10-20        20-30      20-30           10-20
424     20-30        20-30      10-20           0-10
511     0-10         10-20      10-20           30-40
540     10-20        10-20      30-40           60-70
570     10-20        30-40      60-70           70-80
```

after this i would ideally do a frequency/value count to get something like this:

```
      Percentile1 Percentile2 Percentile3   Percentile4
0-10    frequency #'s        
10-20   
20-30   
30-40   
40-50   
etc...
```

any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd probably do something like the following:

```
print df

   Percentile1  Percentile2  Percentile3  Percentile4
0     0.166667     0.266667     0.266667     0.133333
1     0.266667     0.266667     0.133333     0.032258
2     0.032258     0.129032     0.129032     0.387097
3     0.129032     0.129032     0.387097     0.612903
4     0.129032     0.387097     0.612903     0.741935
```

Now use `apply` and `cut` to create a new dataframe that replaces the percentile with the decile bin it is in (apply is iterating over each column):

```
bins = xrange(0,110,10)
new = df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(pd.cut(x*100,bins)))
print new

  Percentile1 Percentile2 Percentile3 Percentile4
0    (10, 20]    (20, 30]    (20, 30]    (10, 20]
1    (20, 30]    (20, 30]    (10, 20]     (0, 10]
2     (0, 10]    (10, 20]    (10, 20]    (30, 40]
3    (10, 20]    (10, 20]    (30, 40]    (60, 70]
4    (10, 20]    (30, 40]    (60, 70]    (70, 80]
```

Use apply once again to get a frequency count:

```
print new.apply(lambda x: x.value_counts()/x.count())

         Percentile1  Percentile2  Percentile3  Percentile4
(0, 10]           0.2          NaN          NaN          0.2
(10, 20]          0.6          0.4          0.4          0.2
(20, 30]          0.2          0.4          0.2          NaN
(30, 40]          NaN          0.2          0.2          0.2
(60, 70]          NaN          NaN          0.2          0.2
(70, 80]          NaN          NaN          NaN          0.2
```

or a value count:

```
print new.apply(lambda x: x.value_counts())

          Percentile1  Percentile2  Percentile3  Percentile4
(0, 10]             1          NaN          NaN            1
(10, 20]            3            2            2            1
(20, 30]            1            2            1          NaN
(30, 40]          NaN            1            1            1
(60, 70]          NaN          NaN            1            1
(70, 80]          NaN          NaN          NaN            1
```

Another approach is not to create the intermediate dataframe (what I called `new`) but just go straight to value counts in one command:

```
print df.apply(lambda x: pd.value_counts(pd.cut(x*100,bins)))

          Percentile1  Percentile2  Percentile3  Percentile4 
(0, 10]             1          NaN          NaN            1
(10, 20]            3            2            2            1
(20, 30]            1            2            1          NaN
(30, 40]          NaN            1            1            1
(60, 70]          NaN          NaN            1            1
(70, 80]          NaN          NaN          NaN            1
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way of doing it if you want `'0-10'` etc, instead of `(20, 30]` provided by `pd.cut`.

```
In [52]:

output = ['0-10','10-20','20-30','30-40','40-50','50-60','60-70','70-80','80-90','90-100']
df2=(df*10).astype(int)
df2=df2.applymap(lambda x: output[x])
print df2
    Percentile1 Percentile2 Percentile3 Percentile4
395       10-20       20-30       20-30       10-20
424       20-30       20-30       10-20        0-10
511        0-10       10-20       10-20       30-40
540       10-20       10-20       30-40       60-70
570       10-20       30-40       60-70       70-80

[5 rows x 4 columns]

In [53]:
print df2.apply(lambda x: x.value_counts()) #or /x.count()
level_1  Percentile1  Percentile2  Percentile3  Percentile4
class                                                      
0-10               1          NaN          NaN            1
10-20              3            2            2            1
20-30              1            2            1          NaN
30-40            NaN            1            1            1
60-70            NaN          NaN            1            1
70-80            NaN          NaN          NaN            1

[6 rows x 4 columns]
```